# Match Exactly column name in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following

```
for col in Features:
     My_Features = pd.merge(My_Features,Drug.ix[:,[col]], left_index = True,right_index=True)
```

which produces the following

```
My_Features.columns
Out[373]: Index([u'**PCBD1_x**', u'**PCBD1_y**', u'KLK8', u'TNFSF13 /// TNFSF12-', u'RIPK5', u'SVIL'], dtype='object')
```

while it should match exactly Features which is

```
Features
Out[375]: ['PCBD1', 'KLK8', 'TNFSF13 /// TNFSF12-', 'RIPK5', 'SVIL']
```

how can I change the "col" match when creating the data frame above .in other words something to avoid  the **BOLD** column matches. it is a regular expression problem.

**Update**

I am trying to extract the columns listed in "Features" from "Drug". Before the

```
for col in Features:
 My_Features = pd.merge(My_Features,Drug.ix[:,[col]], left_index = True,right_index=True)enter code here
```

I have the following line to create the structure for My_Features

```
My_Features =  pd.DataFrame( Drug.ix[:,Features[0]] , index = Drug.index , columns=[Features[0]])
```

so the whole code will look like

```
My_Features =  pd.DataFrame( Drug.ix[:,Features[0]] , index = Drug.index , columns=[Features[0]])
iterfeatures = iter(Features)
next(iterfeatures)
for col in Features:
    My_Features = pd.merge(My_Features,Drug.ix[:,[col]], left_index = True,right_index=True)
```

Comment: What is `pd.merge`?  What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: My_Features is a data frame by itself and I am  merging it with the Drug data frame. The issue is that I want to match something like ^col$  in Drug to avoid any column names that has col as a substring. I think I should have put that in the original problem description, my apology.

Comment: When two DataFrames each have a column with the same name (like 'PCBD1'), and you merge them on the indices and not that column (left_index=True,right_index=True instead of on='PCBD1'), then pandas will rename them to avoid having two columns with the same name (PCBD1_x comes from My_Features and PCBD1_y comes from Drug). Can you explain some more what your end goal is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.filter(). It has a regex argument [as well as a "like" argument]. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html